# Getting the wrong MAC address from ARP command

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, networking, ssh, linux

Disclaimer: new to Linux, using Raspbian light on a Pi 3. SSH access.

I'm trying to look for the mac address using ping / arp:

```
ping 192.168.1.7
arp 192.168.1.7
```

It returns:

```
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
192.168.1.7              ether   02:0f:b5:ed:9e:5c   C                     eth0
```

The HWaddress is different from the mac address I see in Windows:

```
ping 192.168.1.7
arp -a 192.168.1.7

Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
192.168.1.7           c0-ee-fb-ed-9e-5c     dynamic
```

How can I get my Pi to return the same Mac? Note: looks like the 'vendor' part is different.

Comment: What do you see if you type `ifconfig` on your raspberry pi terminal? Raspberry Pi eth0 always has a vendor code of `HWaddr b8:27:eb:xx:xx:xx`

Comment: No idea why, but I'm getting the right IP now.